# Python search for text over multiple lines

Tags: python

```
import os
searchquery = 'word'
with open('Y:/Documents/result.txt', 'w') as f:
for filename in os.listdir('Y:/Documents/scripts/script files'):
    with open('Y:/Documents/scripts/script files/' + filename) as currentFile:
        for line in currentFile:
            if searchquery in line:
                start = line.find(searchquery)
                end = line.find("R")
                result = line[start:end]
                print result
                f.write(result + ' ' +filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

Now this works well to search for "word" and prints everything after word up until an "R" providing that it is on the same line. However if the "R" is on the line it won't print the stuff before it.

eg:

```
this should not be printed!
this should also not be printed! "word" = 12345
6789 "R" After this R should not be printed either!
```

In the case above the 6789 on line 3 will not be printed with my current. However i want it to be. How do i make python keep going over multiple lines until it reaches the "R".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that it does not print the content on the next line because you are searching for the word on one line. A better solution would be as follows.

```
import os
searchquery = 'word'
with open('Y:/Documents/result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for filename in os.listdir('Y:/Documents/scripts/script files'):
        with open('Y:/Documents/scripts/script files/' + filename) as currentFile:              
            content = ''.join([line for line in currentFile])
            start = content.find(searchquery)
            end = content.find("R")
            result = content[start:end].replace("\n", "")
            print result
            f.write(result + ' ' +filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

Please be advised, this will work only for a single occurence. You will need to break it up further to print multiple occurences.